# ng-pluralize hide element when value is 0 (zero)

Tags: angularjs, pluralize, angularjs-ng-pluralize

I would like to user Angulars `ng-pluralize` to hide/show/change an element in such way that of the value is 0, the element should be hidden (as in `ng-hide="value == 0"` or `ng-if="value != 0"`).

When the value is 1, the element should have one text, and if it's more than 1 it should have one text. The value can never be negative. That's why I want to use `ng-pluralize`.

My question is; can you use `ng-pluralize` to do this without having to put the element inside another element just for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of ng-hide and ng-pluralize within the same element

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  //$scope.personCount = 0;
  $scope.personCount = 1;
  //$scope.personCount = 2;
});
```

```css
.myEl {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <ng-pluralize ng-if="personCount > 0" class="myEl" count="personCount" when="{'0': 'Nobody is viewing.',
                     'one': '1 person is viewing.',
                     'other': '{} people are viewing.'}">
  </ng-pluralize>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!